# Parsing year, month, day, hour, minute, second in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a csv file with headers and they are: 
year, month, day, hour, minute, second, firstName

I have the following code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv',  
           parse_dates={'Date/Time': ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']}, 
            index_col=0)
df[:5]
```

When the table is shown the Date/Time column shows as

Date/Time
2013 6 26 18 57 22

instead of

Date/Time
2013-6-26 18:57:22

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `parser` and use it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def parse(year, month, day, hour, minute, second):
    return year+ '-' +month+ '-' +day+ ' ' +hour+ ':' +minute+ ':' +second

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates={'Date/Time':['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']}, 
           date_parser=parse,
           index_col=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it states
ValueError: 'YYYY-MM-DD' is not in list

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer on how this solves the problem

Comment: Thank you Hasan!  That answered my question.